# Inheritance of Permissions Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, inheritance, permissions, subdirectory

I am trying to create a script that will pass down inheritance of the subfolder.

For example:

```
C:/template has x y z permissions
C:/template/test only has x permissions
```

I want all sub folders and files from C:/template to get the x y z permissions.

Something similar to the [script here](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/replace-child-object-permissions-on-existing-folderssubfoldersfiles/)  that Robert Prust made (it does not execute):

```
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path C:\Template
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "C:\new_perm" -Filter 'Subfolder*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
   # write the variables found - check if the folder path is correct
   # Write-Output "This foldername is $Folder"
   # convert foldername to a icacls approved path
   $icacls = "$Folder\*"
   # check if the icacls path is correct
   # Write-Output "icacls path is $icacls"
   #set the ACL required on the folder
   Set-ACL -Path $Folder -AclObject $ACL
   # replace all child permissions for the folder
   icacls $icacls /q /c /t /reset
}
```

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `icacls "C:\template\*" /q /c /t /reset`. It doesn't get simpler than that.

Comment: This does not work, it resets it back to default. For example:
`C:/Template with x y z (z being added manually, x y being defaults)`
When you run your command it sets everything to default:
`C:/Template x y` @ansgarwiechers

Comment: @JonathanDavies My mistake. Since you want to reset permissions on the child elements to the permisions on `C:\template` the path needs to be `C:\template\*`. See updated answer.